# Clicking a button to perform 2 actions: file download & signup

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I’m trying to make it so that whenever the subscribe button is clicked, it performs the sign up (as in the code demoed) but also downloads a file.

I’ve tried to add onclick="window.location.href=‘#’”, but nothing happens. I’ve considered using javascript but I don’t think the subscribe can work this way but I’m confident the file can open that way.

Is there not a simple way to do this to satisfy both outcomes? Other posts do not include an email sign up, which is causing the problem. Would really appreciate some help ;)

```
<form action="http://someuniquemailchimpurl.us16.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=d6f1&amp;id=9ebc2randomlink" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

    <input type="email" placeholder="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">

<div id="mce-responses">

        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>

        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>

    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="newsletter-button">

</form>
```

Comment: What's the programming language you are using? Seems not a client side problem but rather a server side. You can do both on server side.

Comment: I'm just using html, css & javascript and it's all front end. I have no control over the signup back end as it's done by mail chimp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me start off by saying that performing two completely different actions using one button is likely not a good idea. However, you know your business better so you decide, but consider this advice. If you still want to go with that, you have several options, but all of them involve JavaScript.

Before we go with the options, I recommend removing `target="_blank"` from your `form` tag. I removed it in my examples below.

One option is to use the `onclick` event like you're trying to do. The way you're doing it will not work because it will reload the page and the subscription event will not happen. You will need to download the file in a popup window. Here is an example:

```
<form action="http://someuniquemailchimpurl.us16.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=d6f1&amp;id=9ebc2randomlink" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" novalidate>
<input type="submit" onclick="downloadFile()" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="newsletter-button">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadFile() {
        var dw = window.open();
        dw.location.href = "the_file_url";
    }
</script>
```

Another option is to download the file when the form is submitted using the `onsubmit` event on the `form` tag. Here is an example:

```
<form action="http://someuniquemailchimpurl.us16.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=d6f1&amp;id=9ebc2randomlink" method="post" onsubmit="downloadFile()" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" novalidate>
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="newsletter-button">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadFile() {
        var dw = window.open();
        dw.location.href = "the_file_url";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: wow thanks for that! is there any way of doing it with target = "_blank"? the reason I want to perform 2 actions simultaneously is to make the user subscribe to the newsletter to access the file

Comment: just to be clear, your solution only works without target = "_blank"

Comment: You can use `target=_blank", but you will end up creating two popups which are confusing to the user and may get blocked by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event binding and perform two actions. Change post action to download action (or the opposite), then:
 Using jQuery:

```
$('#newsletter-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //although it will not complete properly, ajax call should be ok to signup url
    $.ajax({
        url: 'URL-FROM-SIGN-UP',
        complete: function () {
            // here we submit the form, get(0) needs because submit() from jQuery does not submit a form
            $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').get(0).submit();
        }
    });
});
```